# Icingaweb2 - Setup returns to start page

Tags: monitoring, icinga, system-monitoring

I tried to configure Icingaweb2 on Debian 8; it works fine so far, but if I call the web installer (http://d.pr/186lu) and click "next", I'm getting redirected to the second page (http://d.pr/1f6kE). If I click "next" in this case I'm getting redirected to the start-page again. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved: Just use Chrome or Firefox instead of Safari. That's all!

Comment: You can (should) accept your own answer, too. Click on the pipe icon on the left side.